# Why is difference between form sent from browser and Requests when catched by SimpleHttpServer

Tags: python, http, python-requests, simplehttpserver

I have SimleHttpServer with `do_POST' function

```
def do_POST(self):

    print self.path

    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile, 
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
        })
    for key in form.keys():
        print key
```

And now the problem, If I send the request with browser (HTML form like this)

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="1"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

then values are:

```
self.path = /
form.keys = [a]
```

If I send the same request with python Requests

```
parameters = {
    "a": 2,
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Referer": "http://127.0.0.1:8001/",
    "Host": "127.0.0.1:8001",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8001", params=parameters, headers=headers)
```

the values on server are

```
self.path = /?a=2
form.keys = []
```

Where is the problem? What is different? I copied the headers from browser, so everything should be the same.

Thanks in advance for any help or clue.

**Working workaround:**

If you run into this issue, you can use following workaround in `do_POST` (you need to import cgi, urlparse):

```
    if "?" in self.path:
        qs = self.path.split("?")[1]
        query_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(qs))
    else:       
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=self.rfile, 
            headers=self.headers,
            environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                     'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
            })
        query_dict = {key: form.getvalue(key) for key in form.keys()}
```

But this is not answer for the question.

Comment: You should also try to specify client in `headers`, e.g. `"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)"` or/and use `data=parameters` instead of `params=parameters`

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for reply. I edited my question according to test with "User-Agent". Good idea, unfortunately makes no difference. The `data=parameters` is wrong in concept (but I test it anyway, just to be sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data as POST (i.e. not as GET query-string prameters) you should pass it as `data` parameter, not `params`:

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
>   form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the `data` argument.
>   Your dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the
>   request is made

(Source: [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests))

> `params` -- (optional) Dictionary or bytes to be sent in the **query
>   string** for the Request.
>
> `data` -- (optional) Dictionary or list of
>   tuples [(key, value)] (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like
>   object to send in the **body of the Request**.

(Source: [Main Interface](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#main-interface), emphasis mine)

Comment: It is hard to admit, but you are right. When I test it before I probably made some other mistake/issue what renders it as not working.